# Displaying image on Tianma LCD + Controller Board

Tags: lcd

I want to wire up this board but I don't think I have the proper equipment for it. It's a Tianma LCD with a controller board that is displayed below. It's TM035KDH03.

[image: Controller board]

Here's what it comes with:

[image]

Need help powering this up. If anyone has any separate documentation, that'll also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The four wires on the connector should be all you need to get it working with a composite video source.  The red wire and the black one next to it are for power.  I tested mine using a 9V battery (red is +, black is -).  The yellow wire is the center pin on your composite video cable, and the black wire next to it is the ground of the video cable.

Hope that helps.